# Syntax error in UPDATE statement - Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm getting "Syntax error in UPDATE statement" error message when running the following update in Access from my VB.Net application:

cnn.Open()

```
    Dim strQuery As String = "update MachinesCount set dtEndCount='2/20/2017 9:48:04 PM', Count=0 where ID=15"

    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(strQuery, cnn)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cnn.Close()
```

Any idea what is the error exactly?

Comment: You might try wrapping count in square brackets [Count]=0, pretty sure that's being recognized as a keyword. Also, if dtEndCount is actually a datetime datatype, I think OleDb uses # instead of apostrophes.

Comment: That cant happen when you use SQL paramters

Comment: @CharlesMay that was it! It worked by only adding the brackets [Count]  Thanks!